# Library to format bytes of HTTP response

Tags: python, http, socketserver

I need a library that can only format a correct HTTP response (without creating a web server because I already have this one).

I have to pass a body of an http response and a content type to this library.

The following function does not work properly if I try to send AJAX - jQuery does not find any response. However if I type a corresponding URL in the URL string of browser then a page is displayed.

```
def response( data ):   
    return "HTTP/1.0 200 OK\r\nContent-Type:application/json\r\nConnection:close\r\n\r\n{0}\r\n".format( data )
```

**Details**. The data variable is string of json. I also use the SocketServer class, call self.request.sendall( result_response ) in child's handle() function.

```
# the 'request handler' class
class StateRequestHandler( SocketServer.BaseRequestHandler ):

    def handle( self ):
    ...
        self.request.sendall( response( some_json ) )

# the configured server class
class StateServer( SocketServer.ThreadingMixIn, SocketServer.TCPServer ):
pass
```

**Solved**. The reason was in cross-domain requests.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the following:

1. Although the HTTP 1.0 and 1.1 spec say that a white space is optional between the header name and header value, the specs do say "a single SP[ace] is preferred".
2. Ensure that you do not have any Cross Domain issues so ensure your HTML page is served from exactly the domain,scheme and port as your JSON response (Unless you've correctly configured CORS.
3. Use Chrome Dev Tools / Firebug / Fiddler to see what request they're making and check the Javascript console.
4. Use Wireshark to see exactly what's on the wire.

Comment: Yes, I did not mentioned that domains are probable different. Thank you!